# Ajax Call User % Redirect

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So I just created a test Ajax call function in my script to apply a minimal protection to my website which looks like this:

```
function testPHP() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'file.php',
    success: function() {
      alert("mafak");
    },
    error: function() {
      window.location.href = "https://mywebsiteurl.com";
    }
  });
}
```

And I execute it right after `$(document).ready(function()`. So basically if the file "file.php" doesn't exist, it will redirect the user to my website. So what I need is to redirect only a % of the users by the `window.location.href`.

Let's say 5/10 of the users entering the website will be redirected to mywebsiteurl and the other 5 will stay on the page. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Yes! You need to specify a number of users to be redirect to your url. And No ! You can’t do that for a none specific user numbers.

Comment: you could use a random function to do the job: e.g. Math.random() < 0.5 to specify 50% redirects

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you can use `Math.random()`. That function generates a random number between `0` and `1`. As you want a 50/50 split you can put a condition on that value so that if it's under `0.5` the redirect happens. Try this:

```js
error: function() {
  if (Math.random()< 0.5)
    window.location.assign('https://mywebsiteurl.com');
}
```